# Smarty delete last character from string if it's '/'

Tags: smarty

I'm trying to the last character from a smarty variable.
I knwo that I can delete the last character using `substr` or also replace a character with `replace`.
But I want to delete the last character only if it's ending with `/`

For example my string is `/homepage/`, I would like to become `/homepage`

But If I have `/homepage` it should be `/homepage`

**EDIT :**

Should also work for the string `/homepage/?` -> `/homepage?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Smarty regex_replace](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) and match to `\` if it's the last character with `\/$` and replace it with empty string.

In the same way you can use the `regex_replace` to replace `/?` ending with `?`

`{$variable|regex_replace:"/\/$/":""|regex_replace:"/\/\?$/":"?"}`

Comment: What if my string is `/homepage/` and still want to remove the the last `/`

Comment: The `$variable` is a variable containing your string.

Comment: Yes I know but if my string is `/homepage/?` How can I delete the last `/` ?

Comment: I literally posted the full line you should use. `{$variable|regex_replace:"/\/$/":""}`

Comment: Is the string `/homepage/?` or `/homepage/`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220130/discussion-between-challe-and-executable).

Answer (score 0):

Use the Smarty variable modifier [`regex_replace`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl):

```
{$url|regex_replace:"#/$#":""}
```

Comment: It removes completly my string